# Groups with no nontrivial topology

Tags: topological-groups

Does there exist a group $G$ such that $G$ has no topology on it such that $G$ is a topological group apart from the (in)discrete topology (or other such trivalish topologies)? I am asking as interested in the general methods that one construct a topological group from a group.

I am quite interested in how the problem changes if $G$ is infinite or finite.

Comment: The indiscrete topology also always makes $G$ into a topological group. And to answer your question, take the trivial group.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, usually one includes $T_1$ness into the definition of topological groups.

Comment: From the other side of the coin: if a topological space $G$ can be made into a topological group, the first homotopy group $\pi_1(G,e)$ is abelian. Hence, if $X$ is a topological space with $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ non abelian, it cannot be made into a topological group compatible with this topology.

Comment: @ MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165783/existence-of-infinite-groups-that-are-too-reluctant-to-be-topological/

Comment: (Re: «I am quite interested in how the problem changes if G is infinite or finite.») That's easy to answer: changes from completely trivial (finite) to very hard problem that stayed open for almost 40 years (infinite).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Okay, edited.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks, these are the sort of things I really appreciate in trying to work out how to intuit the topologisation of groups.

Comment: Fortunately one does *not* always assume $T_0/T_1/T_2$ in the definition of topological groups (they are equivalent in this case). Otherwise it's embarrassing when non-Hausdorff groups naturally appear, e.g. as quotients by non-closed normal subgroups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this discussed very nicely in the section about Markov's problems in [these notes](http://www.mat.ucm.es/imi/documents/20062007_Dikran.pdf) by Dikran Dikranjan.

In particular, there do exists groups which have no non-discrete compatible topologies; the notes include the examples of Adian groups,which are countable, and noncountable examples due to Shelah. A nice result is that a group with infinite center has some non-discrete Hausdorff topology.